# Create new column based on the values in a rolling window

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame with a DateTime index and a column containing integers (in this example it only contains 0 and 1):

```
df = {
    "date": pd.date_range(start="2010-01-01 12:00", end="2010-01-01 12:05", freq="T"),
    "values": [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
}
```

```
date                    values
0   2010-01-01 12:00:00 1
1   2010-01-01 12:01:00 0
2   2010-01-01 12:02:00 0
3   2010-01-01 12:03:00 0
4   2010-01-01 12:04:00 1
5   2010-01-01 12:05:00 0
```

I would like to return True if there is a 1 in a rolling time window of 2 minutes, otherwise False, as shown below:

```
date                    values
0   2010-01-01 12:00:00 True      - because the window [1, 0] contains 1
1   2010-01-01 12:01:00 False     - because the window [0, 0] does not contain 1
2   2010-01-01 12:02:00 False
3   2010-01-01 12:03:00 True
4   2010-01-01 12:04:00 True
```

I tried a .groupby() but I didn't get too far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with a datetime index:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

out = (
 df.set_index('date')[::-1]
   .rolling('2min').max()
   .astype(bool)[::-1].reset_index()
)
```

Or:

```
out = (
   df[::-1]
   .rolling('2min', on='date').max()
   .astype({'values': bool})[::-1]
)
```

Output:

```
                 date  values
0 2010-01-01 12:00:00    True
1 2010-01-01 12:01:00   False
2 2010-01-01 12:02:00   False
3 2010-01-01 12:03:00    True
4 2010-01-01 12:04:00    True
5 2010-01-01 12:05:00   False
```